# android speed using COARSE

Tags: android, performance, location

hi to all
how can i get the speed using the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in android

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi are you referring to `Location.getSpeed()` I believe that is an optional field and probably up to the device to actually support it. First off try this

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
LocationProvider[] providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(criteria, false);

if (providers == null || providers.length == 0) {
 //Sorry it doesn't do it by default.
}
```

Luckily Math and Science will help us :) Just calculate the speed as you get updates from your `LocationProviders`. Make sure to calculate the distance between the lat,longs over times as the difference of the recorded times stamps of two Location updates.

```
...
onLocationChanged(Location location) {
 if (mOldLocation != null) {
   float distance = getDistance(mOldLocation, location);
   long time = location.getTime() - mOldLocation.getTime();
   mSpeed = distance/time;
 }
 mOldLocation = location;
}
```

It won't necessarily be greatly accurate (probably really noisy) but it's better to make lemonade than to have rotted fruit ... hopefully this helps. Make sure to only compare deltas across the same provider too. You will probably find yourself tweaking the manual calculation because the devices providers are very diverse and don't guarantee that time always moves forward.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you cannot. Location technology that is "coarse" only knows where you are within several hundred meters. Your speed could vary wildly. If you need to know your speed, you will most likely need a "fine" location provider.

Or, better yet, use the Criteria object to stipulate that you need to know the device's speed, and let it guide you to the best provider to use.

Comment: ok is it possible to get the beginning and end coordinates and time it to took to reach the distention and get an accurate speed out of it

Comment: @Moe: "accurate"? That depends on what you mean. See @Greg's answer.